# Переименовал репозиторий на github, git push теперь не работает

Tags: github

Переименовал репозиторий на github, git push теперь не работает.

Comment: сверите ваш remote с адресом репозитория на github. Проверить ваши remote: git remote -v

Comment: Ответ прими нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Введите и вы увидите, что все еще ссылаетесь на старый урл репозитория

```
git remote -v
```

Обновите урл и все будет работать

```
git remote set-url origin git://NEW_URL
```

[Тут можно почитать подробнее](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)